# Which system for a quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-computer, computer

We are aware that we use binary system for our present day digital computers as they comprise of two states (0&1). But what system would fit the states of a quantum computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest unit of information in a quantum computer is a quantum bit or [qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit). When measured/observed a qubit will be in one of two possible states, which are usually denoted as $|0\text{>}$ and $|1\text{>}$. In between measurments/observations a qubit is in a superposition of these two states.

Answer (score 0):

Some two-level systems can be used as qubits such as the polarizations of photons or the spin of electrons or atoms.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing#Physical_realizations) has quite a comprehensive overview of possible physical implementations, albeit with little additional explanations for some. As far as I know from doing my Master thesis in a experimental quantum optics group, the most common or best developed technqiues nowadays are trapped ions, neutral atoms in an optical lattice, superconducting qubits (Josephson junctions), and quantum dots (single photon sources, essentially).